# Odd behavior when determining indices of tuples that may be undefined in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a type that finds the keys of an object whose values are either optional or unioned with `undefined`, but not required to be `undefined`.

```ts
type MaybeUndefinedKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: undefined extends T[K] ? T[K] extends undefined ? never : K : never;
}[keyof T];
```

This works fine with objects.  Then I thought to test with arrays.

```ts
let x: MaybeUndefinedKeys<[0, 1?]> = '1';

// @ts-expect-error
x = 2; // why does this not throw an error?
```

For some reason, TSC thinks `x` can be the numeric literal `2`, even though the tuple only has indices `0` and `1` and the returned type should be a string.  IntelliSense even suggests `2` as one of the two valid values.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is this a bug in TSC?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAqgOwCYQGYEs0QYDSEIAzgDwAqAfFALxQDeAUFO1ANpFT5QDWpAPbYoVALoBaAPwAuKAFdMOfISgQAHsAiYyY7uKjT9RQ5u27FyvAQxGoBAG4QATlHk95T1wG4WAX05BEBExcT8WABsIYCgNeXgkVGtVYlJKTgAGABooAEZpcTpGAHI8koiAekqoAAFgMklNSABjYCaXFyEXFg0GKAAmHyhqqAB3AAsQKAwhCD1gCdw9NCFYxa6xqDg0dU7u6SA)

Comment: Your type doesn't work as you expect it to work. [playground](https://tsplay.dev/NVObxm)

Comment: It's coming from `[].length` after `{[K in keyof T]:...}` converts yout tuple into **another tuple**. You gonna need an `extends any[]` check

Comment: Yeah, `{[K in keyof T]: ⋯}` on a tuple [yields another tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) and then indexing with `keyof T` gives you every property of that tuple including `length` which is `2`.  If you are going to try to distribute over array keys like this you'll need to handle that somehow, possibly like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoMApN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'm sure one of us will write an answer. If not, what are we missing?

Comment: @jcalz *Almost*.  Suppose I (or someone using my library) had some terrible practices thing like `const x = [0, 1] as [0, 1?] & { a?: number }` and then sets `x.a = 1`.  `Object.keys(x)` would return `['0', '1', 'a']`, but the type would only be `'1'` (missing `'a'`).

Comment: I figured that edge-case out.  I had already defined a type called ArrayObjectKeys which excludes the keys on the Array prototype.  So rather than `[keyof T & (T extends any[] ? number ...]`, I use `... T extends any[] ? ArrayObjectKeys<T> ...`.

Comment: Someone's always going to be able to break your code with bizarre edge cases, and terrible practices beget terrible outcomes. What about `(number | undefined)[]` or `[0, 1?, ...(2 | undefined)[]]`? Do you want to see `number` in the output?  If so, do you want to see `number` in the output of `[0, 1?]`?  If not, by what criteria do we decide? Maybe bonkers edge cases should be out of scope for the question, since I can't see that as anything but a distraction.  I mean, *maybe*, you want something like [this](//tsplay.dev/w2vzVw), but I truly hope we don't need to worry about this stuff *here*.

Comment: @jcalz Hah, totally fair.  I'm just an overengineering purist who wants to cover *every* case, no matter how impractical.  If you want to write up your solution as an answer, I'll mark it so.

Comment: Given that the question as asked is "why is this happening" and @Dimava commented first with the relevant info I'll defer to them if they want to write an answer.